# How to adjust Angular Material styles (not just simple theming ones)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I have the following code:

```
<div>
 <my-custom-component></my-custom-component>
<div>
```

Inside MyCustomComponent's template, I use `mat-card` similar to this:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>{{ name }}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>{{ description }}</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

When it renders, I notice that there is a 16px margin that's given using angular material generated code that looks similar to this:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <div class="mat-card-header-text"> <<< ******** This is the div I am asking about
      <mat-card-title>{{ name }}</mat-card-title>
    </div>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>{{ description }}</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

That div adds `16px` of margin **on top of** the `16px` of padding that the `mat-card` supplies, which pushes the title away from the border of the card by 32 pixels.

The specs of my design say that the title should stay `16px` away from the border not `32px`.

What's the best practice way of how to accomplish this?

Relaying on a `div` that appears there and styling something like `mat-card-header > div` seems wrong since I would be styling this particular implementation of the material card. Next version, this div may end up being some other element.

I could do:

```
mat-card-header mat-card-title {
 margin-left: -16px;
 margin-right: -16px;
}
```

But that again seems kind of hacky to me.

What's the intended way of overriding the internal styles of these components?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that i know

1. Global level:- If you want the style to be applied to all cards in your app, add a 
   style in your styles.scss / css removing the padding / margin to get the required 
   effect.
2. Component level:- If you want this style only inside a particular component where the mat-card is used, add a the style in the component.scss / css file.
   But make sure you use the shadow piercing operator to make the style work.

This approach can be used in other scenarios too. Hope it helps.

Comment: What is a "shadow piercing operator"? The mat-card has its own classes and structure... I feel like targeting that structure is like targeting implementation specific mat-card implementation. Feels hacky to me.

Comment: OH! You mean the /deep/ or ::shadow? Yeah, that's not a good idea and they've been removed from latest browsers... at least in Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing